# Javascript find pixels while canvas is rotated

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to write rotated text (on various angles) on canvas but wish not to overlap the texts. Therefore after rotating the canvas and before filling the text I tried to test the text background using `measureText().width` and `getImageData()` to see that there is no text already there to get messed with new. I fail to find the text (coloured pixels) while the canvas is rotated. Here is a simplified version (using rectangle) to my problem. I wonder why no coloured pixels are found?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid black;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var cWidth=300, cHeight= 150;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// Rotate context around centre point
ctx.translate( cWidth/2, cHeight/2);
ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180);

// Draw 100x50px rectangle at centre of rotated ctx
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.fillRect(-50, -25, 100, 50);

// Is my rotated rectangle really there? 
// i.e. any coloured pixels at rotated cxt centre
imgData = ctx.getImageData(-50, -25, 100, 50);

// All rectangle pixels should be coloured
for (var j=0; j<imgData.data.length; j++){
 if (imgData.data[j] > 0){
  alert ("Coloured");
  break;
 };
};

// Why none is found?

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The yellow rectangle should be at the same spot and angle as the tested image data area is. What went wrong? How I can test the colour of a rotated area? Being novice to Javascript I try to avoid libraries at this stage.

pekka

Comment: Could it be that the array you are copying out here `ctx.getImageData(-50, -25, 100, 50);` doesn't contain the rectangle? Cause this would only contain the data of the image 0 to 50 in width and from 0 to 25 in height. Your canvas is way larger, and the rectangle is positioned in the middle rather at the upper left corner. The getImageData checks from the upper left corner, I don't think it takes your translation points

Comment: @Icepickle is right: `getImageData()` is not influenced by the current transformation matrix. You'll have to do the math, or to draw your canvas on a second one, after inverted the transformation, and get the imageData of this new canvas.

Comment: Thanks! So, as `ctx.getImageData(x,y,w,h)` does not honour the rotation I should `ctx.restore()`the canvas and rotate in opposite direction and then read `ctx.getrImageData()` as it always assumes non-rotated canvas -- right? I wonder if there a list of commands somewhere that do and don't work with rotated/translated canvas...

Comment: WRONG again! Rotating only affects in the drawing commands, not the already drawn stuff or the canvas. The canvas will not get rotated, only the new stuff drawn on the canvas -- right?

Comment: Yes rotating doesn't affect the already drawn stuff nor the export methods. As I said earlier, you'll have to either do the math for your rotated rectangle (keeping in mind that getImageData will pick a non transformed rectangle, and that every pixel will be represented inline as 4 values of your dataArray), or to draw your actual canvas on an other one, get the transformation inverted, so that your coordinates are normal again, and then get the imageData of this later canvas. Personally, given my limited math skills, I'd go to the former, but some here are good and I still hope a real answer.

Comment: Returning to original problem of preventing overlapping text, probably the easiest workaround is to add a new temporary layer (canvas), write new text on it, and compare old text's layer's pixels with new one to determine if both have matching pixels and if so, skip writing the new text amongst old texts. Canvas is fairly large, and there are lots of small text inserts so this comparison will be slow. BTW: How I can mark the question as solved or finished, as the so far best solutions are at comments of original message that I cannot mark as solved?

Comment: @PSi You could either request one of the commentators to answer instead of comment, or you could take what you learned, provide your own answer and mark it as answered, you could also leave the question open so that maybe a better answer comes around in the future, or you could mark one of the already there answers as an answer (and maybe ask if they clarify things a bit better to suit your question). All are acceptable ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `getImageData()` was targeting the wrong portion of the `canvas`. The `x` and `y` coordinates should have the same value of the `translate()` function. This is how your code should look like:

```
// Translate the rectangle, rotate it and fill it 
ctx.translate(cWidth/2, cHeight/2);
ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.fillRect(-50, -25, 100, 50);

// Get the rectangle rotation
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(cWidth/2, cHeight/2, 100, 50);
```

And this is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etzp0sp4/) with the complete code. I hope that my answer helps you!

Comment: Thanks for reply d_z90  Should I use different co-ordinates to `ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h)` and `ctx.getImageData(x,y,w,h)` if canvas was originally rotated? did't change rotation of canvas between drawing and Data-getting. I tried your code snipped, and modified it to count all pixels it found and only got about 1600 px instead of around 5000 px I had expected. Strange...

Comment: That is a possibility, since `getImageData()` calculates it according to an absolute position. Since this question was replied, you can try to ask a new question and copy/paste the link here so that me or someone else can help you.

Comment: so yea, what I said

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the translate function.  You need to account for the displacement.

Try this:

```
imgData = ctx.getImageData(-50+cWidth/2,-25+cHeight/2,100,50);
```

Answer (score 0):

**General purpose answer.**

This answer will work for any type of transformation and relies on the fact that the 2D context transform is mirrored in javascript. It gets the pixels one by one. Another way is to get the pixels as a block by transforming the corners of the rendered box and finding the bounding box that holds the transformed box. Use that box to get the image data. You will still have to transform each pixel address you want to check as the image data will also include extra pixels outside the rendered box. This may be quicker than the solution presented below if the searched for pixels are far and few between, The solution below is better if the odds of finding the pixel you want are high and you can break out of the iterations early.

You will need to use the transform API at the bottom of this answer

```
var mMatrix = new Transform(); // creates a default matrix

// define the bounds 
const box = {x : -50, y : -25, w : 100, h : 50}; // our box


ctx.translate( cWidth/2, cHeight/2); // set the context transform
ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180);
// draw the stuff
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.fillRect(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h);

// mirror the ctx transformations 
mMatrix.translate(cWidth/2, cHeight/2).rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180);
var ix,iy,x,y;
var v = new Transform.Vec(); // create a working vec to save memory usage and anyoning GC hits
for(iy = 0; iy < box.h; iy ++){ // for each vertical pixel
    for(ix = 0; iy < box.w; ix ++){  // for each horizontal
        v.x = ix + 0.5 + box.x; // use pixel center
        v.y = iy + 0.5 + box.y;  
        mMatrix.applyToVec(v); // transform into screen coords.
        v.x = Math.floor(v.x); // get rid of grogens
        v.y = Math.floor(v.y);

        // now we have the pixel address corresponding to the box coordinate ix,iy
        // get one pixel first check if it is on the canvas
        if(v.x >= 0 && v.x < ctx.canvas.width && v.y >= 0 && v.y < ctx.canvas.height){
            var pD = ctx.getImageData(v.x,v.y,1,1).data;
            var red = pD[0];
            var green = pD[1];
            var blue = pD[2];
            var alpha = pD[3];
            // now you have the RGB values
            ... do what ever you want with that info
        }
    }
}
```

**Transform API**

This is the transform API required by the answer. It is a cut down of a API written by me and you can do with what you want (apart from evil things). See answer for usage. It is just the very basics, you can find more comprehensive Transform API on the net (but I don't think you will find one much faster)

See comment at the bottom for method details. Most functions are chainable.

Code snippet runs nothing.

```js
var Transform = (function () {
    var tx, ty, v1, v2, v3, mat;
    // work vecs and transform provide pre assigned working memory
    v1 = new Vec();
    v2 = new Vec();
    v3 = new Vec();
    mat = new Transform();
    ty = tx = 0;
    
    function Transform(xAxisX, xAxisY, yAxisX, yAxisY, originX, originY) {
        if (xAxisX === undefined) { // create identity matrix
            this.xAxis = new Vec(); // Default vec is 1,0
            this.yAxis = new Vec(0, 1);
            this.origin = new Vec(0, 0);
        } else if (yAxisY === undefined) { // if only 3 arguments assume that the 3 arguments are vecs
            this.xAxis = new Vec(xAxisX.x, xAxisX.y); //
            this.yAxis = new Vec(xAxisY.x, xAxisY.y);
            this.origin = new Vec(yAxisY.x, xAxisY.y);
        } else {
            this.xAxis = new Vec(xAxisX, xAxisY); // Default vec is 1,0
            this.yAxis = new Vec(yAxisX, yAxisY);
            this.origin = new Vec(originX, originY);
        }
    };
    function Vec(x, y) {
        if (x === undefined || x === null) {
            this.x = 1;
            this.y = 0;
        } else {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    };
    Vec.prototype = {
        copy : function () {
            return new Vec(this.x, this.y);
        },
        setAs : function (vec, y) { // set this to the value of vec, or if two arguments vec is x and y is y
            if (y !== undefined) {
                this.x = vec;
                this.y = y;
                return this;
            }
            this.x = vec.x;
            this.y = vec.y;
            return this;
        }
    }
    Transform.prototype = {
        xAxis : undefined,
        yAxis : undefined,
        origin : undefined,
        Vec : Vec, // expose the Vec interface
        copy : function () {
            return new Transform(this.xAxis, this.yAxis, this.origin);
        },
        setAs : function (transform) {
            this.xAxis.x = transform.xAxis.x;
            this.xAxis.y = transform.xAxis.y;
            this.yAxis.x = transform.yAxis.x;
            this.yAxis.y = transform.yAxis.y;
            this.origin.x = transform.origin.x;
            this.origin.y = transform.origin.y;
            return;
        },
        reset : function () { // resets this to the identity transform
            this.xAxis.x = 1;
            this.xAxis.y = 0;
            this.yAxis.x = 0;
            this.yAxis.y = 1;
            this.origin.x = 0;
            this.origin.y = 0;
            return this;
        },
        apply : function (x, y) { // returns an object {x : trabsformedX, y : trabsformedY} the returned object does not have the Vec prototype
            return {
                x : x * this.xAxis.x + y * this.yAxis.x + this.origin.x,
                y : x * this.xAxis.y + y * this.yAxis.y + this.origin.y
            };
        },
        applyToVec : function (vec) { // WARNING returns this not the vec.
            tx = vec.x * this.xAxis.x + vec.y * this.yAxis.x + this.origin.x;
            vec.y = vec.x * this.xAxis.y + vec.y * this.yAxis.y + this.origin.y;
            vec.x = tx;
            return this;
        },
        invert : function () { // inverts the transform
            // first check if just a scale translated identity matrix and invert that as it is quicker
            if (this.xAxis.y === 0 && this.yAxis.x === 0 && this.xAxis.x !== 0 && this.yAxis.y !== 0) {
                this.xAxis.x = 1 / this.xAxis.x;
                this.xAxis.y = 0;
                this.yAxis.x = 0;
                this.yAxis.y = 1 / this.yAxis.y;
                this.origin.x = -this.xAxis.x * this.origin.x;
                this.origin.y = -this.yAxis.y * this.origin.y;
                return this;
            }
            var cross = this.xAxis.x * this.yAxis.y - this.xAxis.y * this.yAxis.x;
            v1.x = this.yAxis.y / cross;
            v1.y = -this.xAxis.y / cross;
            v2.x = -this.yAxis.x / cross;
            v2.y = this.xAxis.x / cross;
            v3.x = (this.yAxis.x * this.origin.y - this.yAxis.y * this.origin.x) / cross;
            v3.y =  - (this.xAxis.x * this.origin.y - this.xAxis.y * this.origin.x) / cross;
            this.xAxis.x = v1.x;
            this.xAxis.y = v1.y;
            this.yAxis.x = v2.x;
            this.yAxis.y = v2.y;
            this.origin.x = v3.x;
            this.origin.y = v3.y;
            return this;
        },
        asInverse : function (transform) { // creates a new or uses supplied transform to return the inverse of this matrix
            if (transform === undefined) {
                transform = new Transform();
            }
            if (this.xAxis.y === 0 && this.yAxis.x === 0 && this.xAxis.x !== 0 && this.yAxis.y !== 0) {
                transform.xAxis.x = 1 / this.xAxis.x;
                transform.xAxis.y = 0;
                transform.yAxis.x = 0;
                transform.yAxis.y = 1 / this.yAxis.y;
                transform.origin.x = -transform.xAxis.x * this.origin.x;
                transform.origin.y = -transform.yAxis.y * this.origin.y;
                return transform;
            }
            var cross = this.xAxis.x * this.yAxis.y - this.xAxis.y * this.yAxis.x;
            transform.xAxis.x = this.yAxis.y / cross;
            transform.xAxis.y = -this.xAxis.y / cross;
            transform.yAxis.x = -this.yAxis.x / cross;
            transform.yAxis.y = this.xAxis.x / cross;
            transform.origin.x = (this.yAxis.x * this.origin.y - this.yAxis.y * this.origin.x) / cross;
            transform.origin.y =  - (this.xAxis.x * this.origin.y - this.xAxis.y * this.origin.x) / cross;
            return transform;
        },
        multiply : function (transform) { // multiplies this with transform
            var tt = transform;
            var t = this;
            v1.x = tt.xAxis.x * t.xAxis.x + tt.yAxis.x * t.xAxis.y;
            v1.y = tt.xAxis.y * t.xAxis.x + tt.yAxis.y * t.xAxis.y;
            v2.x = tt.xAxis.x * t.yAxis.x + tt.yAxis.x * t.yAxis.y;
            v2.y = tt.xAxis.y * t.yAxis.x + tt.yAxis.y * t.yAxis.y;
            v3.x = tt.xAxis.x * t.origin.x + tt.yAxis.x * t.origin.y + tt.origin.x;
            v3.y = tt.xAxis.y * t.origin.x + tt.yAxis.y * t.origin.y + tt.origin.y;
            t.xAxis.x = v1.x;
            t.xAxis.y = v1.y;
            t.yAxis.x = v2.x;
            t.yAxis.y = v2.y;
            t.origin.x = v3.x;
            t.origin.y = v3.y;
            return this;
        },
        rotate : function (angle) { // Multiply matrix by rotation matrix at angle
            var xdx = Math.cos(angle);
            var xdy = Math.sin(angle);
            v1.x = xdx * this.xAxis.x + (-xdy) * this.xAxis.y;
            v1.y = xdy * this.xAxis.x + xdx * this.xAxis.y;
            v2.x = xdx * this.yAxis.x + (-xdy) * this.yAxis.y;
            v2.y = xdy * this.yAxis.x + xdx * this.yAxis.y;
            v3.x = xdx * this.origin.x + (-xdy) * this.origin.y;
            v3.y = xdy * this.origin.x + xdx * this.origin.y;
            this.xAxis.x = v1.x;
            this.xAxis.y = v1.y;
            this.yAxis.x = v2.x;
            this.yAxis.y = v2.y;
            this.origin.x = v3.x;
            this.origin.y = v3.y;
            return this;
        },
        scale : function (scaleX, scaleY) { // Multiply the matrix by scaleX and scaleY
            this.xAxis.x *= scaleX;
            this.xAxis.y *= scaleY;
            this.yAxis.x *= scaleX;
            this.yAxis.y *= scaleY;
            this.origin.x *= scaleX;
            this.origin.y *= scaleY;
            return this;
        },
        translate : function (x, y) { // Multiply the matrix by translate Matrix
            this.origin.x += x;
            this.origin.y += y;
            return this;
        },
        setTransform : function (xAxisX, xAxisY, yAxisX, yAxisY, originX, originY) {
            this.xAxis.x = xAxisX;
            this.xAxis.y = xAxisY;
            this.yAxis.x = yAxisX;
            this.yAxis.y = yAxisY;
            this.origin.x = originX;
            this.origin.y = originY;
            return this;
        },
        transform : function (xAxisX, xAxisY, yAxisX, yAxisY, originX, originY) {
            var t = this;
            v1.x = xAxisX * t.xAxis.x + yAxisX * t.xAxis.x;
            v1.y = xAxisY * t.xAxis.x + yAxisY * t.xAxis.y;
            v2.x = xAxisX * t.yAxis.x + yAxisX * t.yAxis.x;
            v2.y = xAxisY * t.yAxis.x + yAxisY * t.yAxis.y;
            v3.x = xAxisX * t.origin.x + yAxisX * t.origin.y + originX;
            v3.y = xAxisY * t.origin.x + yAxisY * t.origin.y + originY;
            t.xAxis.x = v1.x;
            t.xAxis.y = v1.y;
            t.yAxis.x = v2.x;
            t.yAxis.y = v2.y;
            t.origin.x = v3.x;
            t.origin.y = v3.y;
            return this;
        },
        contextTransform : function (ctx) {
            ctx.transform(this.xAxis.x, this.xAxis.y, this.yAxis.x, this.yAxis.y, this.origin.x, this.origin.y);
            return this;
        },
        contextSetTransform : function (ctx) {
            ctx.Settransform(this.xAxis.x, this.xAxis.y, this.yAxis.x, this.yAxis.y, this.origin.x, this.origin.y);
            return this;
        },
        setFromCurrentContext : function(ctx){
            if(ctx && typeof ctx.currentTransform === "object"){
                var mat = ctx.currentTransform;
                this.xAxis.x = mat.a;
                this.xAxis.y = mat.b;
                this.yAxis.x = mat.c;
                this.yAxis.y = mat.d;
                this.origin.x = mat.e;
                this.origin.y = mat.f;
            }
            return this;
        }
            
    }
    if(typeof document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d").currentTransform !== "object"){
        Transform.prototype.setFromCurrentContext = undefined;
    }
    return Transform;
})();


/*
rotate(angle) // Multiply matrix by rotation matrix at angle. Same as ctx.rotate
scale(scaleX, scaleY) // Multiply the matrix by scaleX and scaleY. Same as ctx.scale
translate(x, y) // Multiply the matrix by translate Matrix. Same as ctx.translate
setTransform(xAxisX, xAxisY, yAxisX, yAxisY, originX, originY)  //Replaces the current reansform with the new values. Same as ctx.setTransform
transform(xAxisX, xAxisY, yAxisX, yAxisY, originX, originY) // multiplies this transform with the supplied transform. Same as ctx.transform 


Transform.xAxis  // Vec object defining the direction and scale of the x Axis. Values are in canvas pixel coordinates
Transform.yAxis  // Vec object defining the direction and scale of the y Axis. Values are in canvas pixel coordinates
Transform.origin  // Vec object defining canvas pixel coordinates of the origin
Transform.Vec // interface to a vec object with basic interface needed to support Transform
Transform.reset() // resets the transform to the identity matrix (the default matrix used by 2D context)
Transform.copy() // creates a new copy of this object 
Transform.setAs(transform)  // sets the content of this to the values of the argument transform
Transform.apply(x, y) { // Transforms the coords x,y by multiplying them with this. Returns an object {x : trabsformedX, y : trabsformedY} the returned object does not have the Vec prototype
Transform.applyToVec(vec) // transforms the point vec. WARNING returns this not the vec.
Transform.invert() // inverts the transform
Transform.asInverse(transform) // creates a new or uses supplied transform to return the inverse of this matrix
Transform.multiply(transform) // multiplies this with transform
Transform.contextTransform(ctx) // multiplies the supplied context (ctx) transform by this.
Transform.contextSetTransform(ctx) // set the supplied context (ctx) transform to this
Transform.setFromCurrentContext(ctx)  // Only for supported browser. Sets this to the supplied context current transformation. May not be available if there is no browser support

 
There is also access to the very simple Vec object. To create a vec `new Transform.Vec(x,y)`


*/
```

Comment: If you anyhow take the time to write such an extensive reply, why not show how easy it use it on his sample code?

Comment: @Icepickle Sadly I live in backwater ....vile where the internet connection comes and goes at a whim, That is the second version, and as I lost most of the first I can not be bothered adding more, the OP can just copy all the code and it will run with but minor changes to suit their particular need.

Comment: @Blindman67: Thanks for seeing the trouble of writing the code. As I said, I'm a novice to Javascript. Not wishing to sound ungrateful, but you just made me realise just how novice I really am. Do not get me wrong: I did not wish or expect a complete turn-key solution, just a push into right direction. The solution to me was to realise what `ctx.rotate()` is actually rotating.